# Why is urllib.urlopen() only working once? - Python

Tags: python, web-crawler, urllib2, urllib

I'm writing a crawler to download the static html pages using `urllib`.

The get_page function works for 1 cycle but when i try to loop it, it doesn't open the content to the next url i've fed in.

- **How do i make `urllib.urlopen` continuously download HTML pages?**
- *If it is not possible, is there any other suggestion to download
  webpages within my python code?*

my code below only returns the html for the 1st website in the `seed` list:

```
import urllib
def get_page(url):
    return urllib.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')

seed = ['http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/home.html', 
            'http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/aboutpmo.html']    

for j in seed:
      print "here"
      print get_page(j)
```

The same crawl "once-only" problem also occurs with `urllib2`:

```
import urllib2
def get_page(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response.read().decode('utf8')

seed = ['http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/home.html', 
            'http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/aboutpmo.html']    

for j in seed:
      print "here"
      print get_page(j)
```

Without the exception, i'm getting an IOError with urllib:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvas/workspace/SingCorp/sgcrawl.py", line 91, in <module>
    print get_page(j)
  File "/home/alvas/workspace/SingCorp/sgcrawl.py", line 4, in get_page
    return urllib.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 462, in open_file
    return self.open_local_file(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 476, in open_local_file
    raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/aboutpmo.html'
```

Without the exception, i'm getting a ValueError with urllib2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alvas/workspace/SingCorp/sgcrawl.py", line 95, in <module>
    print get_page(j)
  File "/home/alvas/workspace/SingCorp/sgcrawl.py", line 7, in get_page
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 392, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 254, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/aboutpmo.html
```

**ANSWERED:**

The IOError and ValueError occurred because there was some sort of Unicode byte order mark (BOM). A non-break space was found in the second URL. Thanks for all your help and suggestion in solving the problem!!

Comment: have you manually checked that these websites are indeed different?

Comment: one thing to note, your import should be at the top of the file, not in a try except block.

Comment: Try printing something in the exception handler, to see if you get an exception.

Comment: @antti, i've tried printing a note at the exception.
The urllib.open is just not working after the 1st time that's why it ran into the `except` .
@hayden, imports at the top of the file is expensive. Especially in crawling.

Comment: It's not a solution, but due to the way Python has evolved over the years, you should be using `urllib2.urlopen`... and if you don't mind 3rd party modules, then using `requests` is highly recommended

Comment: You also don't require the `\` to multi-line a list

Comment: @JonClements, see above, urllib2 is also not working.

Comment: But you haven't updated the question `urllib` is expecting to open a local file... File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 476, in open_local_file

Comment: This works fine for me: `>>> import urllib2
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/home.html')`

Comment: @JonClements, See above, updated the error for `urllib2`, it's a different error for `urllib` and `urllib2`

Comment: @JonClements, my 1st `urlopen` works, **my 2nd doesn't**. That is the problem. A single line `urlopen` works for me too

Comment: i get the error even while trying this `>> seed = ['http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/home.html', 'http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/aboutpmo.html']`

`>> for i in seed:`
`>>  print urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(i)).read()`

Comment: I have to ask. Is there any reason why you're not using an existing framework like [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)?

Comment: @Ben, because i dont know about it until now. hahahaha. I'll give it a try if this urllib is giving 101 problems.

Comment: @Ben, do you know how Scrapy is downloading the pages as a crawler?

Comment: No, but it's [open source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy) so you can look for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your examples work fine for me.  The only explanation I can think of for your exact errors is that the second URL string contains some sort of non-printable character (a Unicode BOM, perhaps) that got filtered out when pasting the code here.  Try copying the code back from this site into your file, or retyping the entire second string from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

your code is choking on `.read().decode('utf8')`.

but you wouldn't see that since you are just swallowing exceptions.  `urllib` works fine "more than once".

```
import urllib

def get_page(url):
    return urllib.urlopen(url).read()

seeds = ['http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/home.html', 
            'http://www.pmo.gov.sg/content/pmosite/aboutpmo.html']    

for seed in seeds:
      print 'here'
      print get_page(seed)
```

Comment: after removing the exception, i'm still getting the IOError as above.

Comment: 2er0, this is a question/answer site, not a crowdsourced interactive debugger.  ask a question, get an answer, move to the next question.  don't keep editing your code and question and re-asking different things.

Comment: it's the same problem and question. I've just made it more readable. =)

Comment: oh i've found the problem!!! somehow Jasonharper was right. the second URL contained some sort of unicode BOM.